# Exception after adding JAX-RS facet to Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rest, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3, jax-rs

I am a newbie to Oracle Plugin for Eclipse (OEPE) and EJB. I am following the tutorial on  following the tutorial on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=on557289GzA&feature=relmfu titled JavaEE6 and Glassfish with Eclipse (5 of 5)

I am getting the following exception after I enable JAX-RS facet for the Dyanamic Web Project.

Exception while loading the app : java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

I recreated a new environment (Eclipse Indigo, Glassfish 3.0.1) but I am struck at the same point. There is a already a question on the same topic. But it is marked answered without answer or even a hint!!

Please help me.

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="OpenEducation">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/ScottConn</jta-data-source>
        <class>model.Course</class>
        <class>model.Customer</class>
        <class>model.Registration</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>OpenEducation</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You must have in your project at least one class marked with @Path JAX-RS annotation.